# Did the empresario system exist only within Mexican Texas?

Tags: law, mexico, land, texas

I have many sources describing the empresario system, a way to encourage settlement of Texas. Every source I could find mentioned "Texas". I cannot find any sources using this terminology referring to other parts of Mexico. This was implemented starting after the Mexican War of Independence when Texas was still part of Mexico, before Texas' independence.

Was the empresario system exclusive to Texas?

Comment: For the most part yes only in Texas, though there are some oddities that may "technically" count like Phillip Alston.

Answer (score 3):

The empresario system started way before Mexico was independent, so the answer will depend on whether you consider empresarios appointed by Spain as counting or not.  If so then, [Philip Alston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Alston_(counterfeiter)), in 1790, was appointed an empresario in New Madrid (Missouri) and before him George Morgan was appointed empresario there by Spain.

> European Americans renamed the settlement New Madrid in about 1780
> under the auspices of Spanish Governor Bernardo de Gálvez, who was
> appointed to rule Spanish Louisiana (the land west of the Mississippi
> River), and Manuel Pérez, Lieutenant Governor of Upper Louisiana in
> Saint Louis. They welcomed settlers from the United States, but
> required them to become subjects of the Spanish crown. In addition,
> they had to agree to live under the guidance of his appointed
> empresario, Colonel George Morgan, an American Revolutionary War
> veteran from New Jersey. Morgan recruited a number of American
> families to settle at New Madrid, attracting a few hundred people to
> the region. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Madrid,_Missouri)